# Parsing nested JSON in RestKit for iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

Here is the JSON I am trying to parse: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Name,LastTradePriceOnly%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20('YHOO','AAPL','GOOG','MSFT')&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

(I couldn't get it to format correctly on here so thats why I provided a link.)

```
{

    "query": {
        "count": 4,
        "created": "2014-12-08T02:46:32Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "quote": [
                {
                    "LastTradePriceOnly": "50.99",
                    "Name": "Yahoo! Inc."
                },
                {
                    "LastTradePriceOnly": "115.00",
                    "Name": "Apple Inc."
                },
                {
                    "LastTradePriceOnly": "525.26",
                    "Name": "Google Inc."
                },
                {
                    "LastTradePriceOnly": "48.42",
                    "Name": "Microsoft Corpora"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

I am wanting to get the information from the "quote" section but I don't know how to get down there.

Here is my code:

```
func getSampleStocksFromYahoo(query:String, successBlock:StocksResponseSuccessBlock, failureBlock:StocksResponseFailureBlock){

    let url = NSURL(string:query)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)


    var stockMapping:RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass:Stock.self)
        stockMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["Name":"name"])

    var rDescriptor:RKResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: stockMapping, method: RKRequestMethod.GET, pathPattern: nil, keyPath: nil, statusCodes: nil)

    var request:RKObjectRequestOperation = RKObjectRequestOperation(request: urlRequest, responseDescriptors: [rDescriptor])

    request.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(successBlock, failure: failureBlock)
    request.start()


}
```

How do I set my mapping so it starts at the "quote" section?

Comment: The XML file link you have provided is saying its missing some arguments for some reason.

Comment: Hi Sean, half of the link is not clickable. If you could copy and paste the entire url, it will work.

Comment: Wow. Sorry about that let me look at everything really fast.  I guess I forgot to highlight the last callback part as well.

Comment: So I know how to do this but I can not port this to Swift correctly as I do not know a lot about the language? Would you want to see the objective c code?

Comment: The objective-C code would be perfectly fine!

Comment: Formatted fine when I tried.

Comment: That's not "nested JSON", it's just plain vanilla JSON.

Comment: I'm new to JSON so I have no idea what vanilla, chocolate, or strawberry JSON is :)

Comment: Have you read about what the `keyPath` parameter on the response descriptor does?

Comment: @Wain, yes I have. I just don't what I need to put as the path that leads up to the quote section

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this took so long to post as I was away doing something.  You said an objective-c answer would be fine instead of Swift so here you go!

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Name,LastTradePriceOnly%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20('YHOO','AAPL','GOOG','MSFT')&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback="]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpUrlResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    if (!connectionError && httpUrlResponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
        if (!jsonError)
        {
            NSArray *quotes = [[[responseDictionary objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"quote"];

            for (int index = 0; index < quotes.count; index++)
            {
                NSDictionary *quoteInformation = [quotes objectAtIndex:index];
                NSLog(@"Name: %@", [quoteInformation objectForKey:@"Name"]);
                NSLog(@"LastTradePriceOnly: %@", [quoteInformation objectForKey:@"LastTradePriceOnly"]);
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Even though this was not exactly what I was looking for since this code does not involve RestKit, this solution is perfectly acceptable. I tested the code myself and it works perfectly. Thank you Sean

Comment: No problem and I can make a RestKit version if you would like.

Comment: If you have the time and wouldn't mind doing it, that would be absolutely wonderful and I would graciously appreciate your time and effort! :-)